# How to do restrict keyword inside special lines?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, multiple-lines

I am trying to write a VIM highlight file for Gaussian 09 inputs. One example of "control" line is shown below:

```
# P TPSSTPSS 6-31G* DENSITYFIT
  OPT(VERYTIGHT) INT(ULTRAFINE)
  FREQ(NORAMAN)

TITLE LINE, NOT CONTROL LINE, SO OPT HERE SHOULD NOT HIGHLIGHT
```

The point is, if a `#` mark is found at the beginning of the line, then the following lines are concatenated until an empty line is found, and the words are considered as keywords, e.g. `OPT` is a keyword in the second row, however it is no longer a keyword in the fifth row.

How do I let the `syntax` command in VIM know it needs to join them, and restrict the keywords inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a syntax region. Basically you have to define that your keywords will be contained in a region and then define the region that they will be contained in. Like so:

```
syn keyword ConcatKeywords OPT INT FREQ contained
syn region Concat start='^#' end='^$' contains=ConcatKeywords
```

The important part here is the `contained` option after the first line and the `contains=` option after the second line. This will make vim look for these keywords *only* in the regions that have it `contained`.

You will, of course, then need to highlight your keywords. You can define your own or link it to an already exsisting highlight:

```
hi link ConcatKeywords PreProc
```

For more info I would recommend [this great tutorial on the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files), as well as these help documents: `:h syn-keyword`, `:h syn-match`, and `:h syn-region`